# javascript error: "Cannot read property 'value' of null" on input spinner for multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, dom

I've run into an issue where I need to have a quantity spinner on multiple items (with unique id's) on the same page.

Example:

[image]

This is the javascript I'm using, which works perfectly when there is only one input with the given id (product_quantity). But then when I have multiple items they each have unique id's (of course), so it fails

```
function updateSpinner(obj)
{
    var contentObj = document.getElementById("product_quantity");
    var value = parseInt(contentObj.value);
    if(obj.id == "down") {
        value--;
    } else {
        value++;
    }
    contentObj.value = value >= 1 ? value : 1;
}
```

(example found on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AmanVirdi/hbP3y/)

HTML for the single element I have this working on:

```
<div class="quantity-controls">
    <a class="button" id="down" onclick="updateSpinner(this);">...</a>
    <input type="text" name="quantity" id="product_quantity" value="1">
    <a class="button" id="up" onclick="updateSpinner(this);">...</a>
</div>
```

The html output for 2 *dynamic* input fields (each has the same surrounding html as above):

```
<input type="text" class="qty-val" name="quantity[01]" id="product_quantity_01" value='1'>
<input type="text" class="qty-val" name="quantity[02]" id="product_quantity_02" value='1'>
```

How could I modify the javascript to work with something like this? Or should I be taking a different approach?

I did try modifying it to this (but then it just didn't work at all):

```
function updateSpinner(obj)
{
    var contentObj = document.getElementsByClassName("qty-val");
    var value = parseInt(contentObj.value);
    if(obj.id == "down") {
        value--;
    } else {
        value++;
    }
    contentObj.value = value >= 1 ? value : 1;
}
```

Comment: How is `updateSpinner` supposed to know which element it should choose? Pass the right element as argument maybe?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know javascript very well, but yeah that is the issue, that "product_quantity" is not a valid id for each... how could I pass the right element as an argument?

Comment: That depends on how `updateSpinner` is called I guess.

Comment: What further information can I provide? Again, I know very little javascript...

Comment: How are the +/- buttons associated with the input that holds the value? How is the (presumably *click*) listener added? How is the *update* function called? See [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok gotcha, I updated my question with the html for the +/- buttons which also have the onclick event

Comment: Passing the corresponding input element could be as simple as `updateSpinner(this, this.nextElementSibling);` and `updateSpinner(this, this.previousElementSibling);`, but note that `nextElementSibling` and `previousElementSibling` are not supported in IE8 and below. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling .

Comment: @FelixKling, lol, same idea! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, since you use onclick event handler in html, you can do something llike this:

```js
function updateSpinner(elem,obj)
{
value = parseInt(obj.value);   


    if(elem.id.indexOf("down")>-1) {

        value--;
    } else {
        value++;
    }
   obj.value = value >= 1 ? value : 1;
}
```

```css
a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    color:white;
    background:green;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:50%;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:30px;
}
```

```html
<a id="down1" href="#" onclick="updateSpinner(this,this.nextElementSibling);">-</a>
<input type="text" class="qty-val" name="quantity[02]" id="product_quantity_02" value='1'>
<a id="up1" href="#"  onclick="updateSpinner(this,this.previousElementSibling);">+</a><br>
<a id="down2" href="#" onclick="updateSpinner(this,this.nextElementSibling);">-</a>
<input type="text" class="qty-val" name="quantity[02]" id="product_quantity_02" value='1'>
<a id="up2" href="#"  onclick="updateSpinner(this,this.previousElementSibling);">+</a>
```

I have used this and previousElementSibling and nextElementSibling - to add references to current button and text field.

Answer (score 1):

You need to associate the + and - buttons with the related input displaying the count. I've used a *data-* attribute linked to ID so that the layout is independent of the script, there are other ways. You could also use a *data-* attribute to identify whether to add to or subtract from the total.

Likely want to add the listeners dynamically, the following example uses inline listeners.

```js
function update(element, num) {
  var target = document.getElementById(element.dataset.id);
  var value;
  if (target) {
    value = parseInt(target.value) + parseInt(num);
    // Don't allow to go below zero
    target.value = value > -1? value : 0;
  }
}
```

```html
Item 1: <button onclick="update(this, 1)" data-id="item1">+</button><input type="text" id="item1" value="0"><button onclick="update(this, -1)" data-id="item1">-</button>
<br>
Item 2: <button onclick="update(this, 1)" data-id="item2">+</button><input type="text" id="item2" value="0"><button onclick="update(this, -1)" data-id="item2">-</button>
<br>
Item 2: <button onclick="update(this, 1)" data-id="item3">+</button><input type="text" id="item3" value="0"><button onclick="update(this, -1)" data-id="item3">-</button>
```